# How do I find a function $f(3n) = 3n$ such that it is different from the identity function?

Tags: functions

This is my first time posting. I'm sorry if I'm neglecting some good etiquette practices; I tried to read everything that's been sent my way, but I probably missed something anyway. Also, English is not my first language, so I'm relying on Google to translate math-specific terminology. If something isn't clear, please let me know!

I'm a Computer Science student at University, and I've been requested to find a function $f: \Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$,  $f(3n) = 3n \land f\neq \mathrm{id}_\Bbb {N}$. I absolutely cannot find a solution, as $f(x) = x$ (and, as such, $f(3n) = 3n$ too)  literally *is* the definition of identity function as far as I know... Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $f(3n)=3n, f(3n+1)=3n+2$, and $f(3n+2)=3n+1$?

Comment: or how about $f(n)=n$ for $n\ne1$, and $f(1)=2?$

Comment: Basically you want $f|_{3\mathbb N}$ ($f$ restricted to multiples of $3$) to be the identity function but not $f$

Comment: $f(n)=3\cdot \Big\lceil \frac{n}{3} \Big\rceil$ ($\lceil . \rceil$ is the ceiling function) works for $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $f|_{3\mathbb N}$ ($f$ restricted to multiples of $3$) to be the identity function

but $f$ not to be the identity function.

There are many ways to accomplish this; others have given some.  Here are two alternatives:

(a)  $f(n)=n$ for $n\ne1$ and $f(1)=2$

(b)  $f(3n)=3n$, $f(3n+1)=3n+2$, and $f(3n+2)=3n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

What about$$f(n)=\begin{cases}n&\text{ if }3\mid n\\1&\text{ otherwise?}\end{cases}$$Then you have $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f(3n)=3n$, right?!

Comment: What about f(3*4) and 3*f(4)? IMHO f(3*4) = 12, but 3*f(4) = 3.

Comment: @MarianD:  as far as I know, there's no requirement here that $f(3\times4)=3\times f(4)$, only that $f(3\times4)=3\times4$

Comment: @J.W. - oh, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb{N}$, so the equation

$$f(3n) =3n\tag1$$

means

\begin{align}
&f(3) = 3\\
&f(6) = 6\\
&f(9) = 9\\
&\cdots \cdots \cdots
\end{align}

so for natural numbers *other than multiple of $3$*, the function $f$ may have $any$ natural value and *still satisfy the equation $(1)$.*

So it is sufficient to assign e.g. $f(2) = 100$, and for all other natural numbers $f(n) = n$.